# Android Firebase Database : Delete

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following database structure:

[image]

I need to delete a child (both key and value), for example, the first one, by knowing his value: `xzFD1RahhZYr05nZljIW9BRzvSq1`

So I have

```
String itemToDelete = "xzFD1RahhZYr05nZljIW9BRzvSq1";
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
databaseReference deleteRef=database.getReference("richieste").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
deleteRef.orderByValue().equalTo(itemToDelete);
deleteRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        //What to do with .removeValue(); ?
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
}
```

I don't know exactly what to do with `dataSnapshot` to remove the child

Thank you for the answer

---

Bonus question: what should I do with `onCancelled` event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Willik's answer covers the important issues.  The code below implements them all.

**Update for Comments:**
[Query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query) is a class in the Firebase SDK.  You should be able to import it:

```
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
```

If `dataSnapshot.exists()` is false, it means there is no data in the database at `/richieste/$uid`.  Check that the UID of the signed-in user is what you expect and there is data for that UID in your database.

```
    String itemToDelete = "xzFD1RahhZYr05nZljIW9BRzvSq1";

    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference deleteRef = database.getReference("richieste")
        .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
    // orderByValue() and equalTo() return a query; can't use the original reference
    Query deleteQuery = deleteRef.orderByValue().equalTo(itemToDelete);
    deleteQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                // If the value to delete is not unique, there may be multiple children
                for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    // TODO Should also check the result of removeValue()
                    // using a CompletionListener or the returned Task
                    // in case you don't have write access
                    child.getRef().removeValue();
                    Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: Removed " + child.getKey());
                }
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            // Often get here because of a protection violation;
            // i.e. the security rules are not set to grant read access.
            // One option is to log the failure
            Log.e(TAG, "onCancelled: FAILED " + databaseError.getMessage());
            // Or you can also throw the exception
            throw databaseError.toException();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you very much. However it's not working. datasnapshot.exists is always false and does not do anything

I had to merge to rows because Query class was not being recognized and android studio did not suggest any import, not sure if I am doing it correctly:

deleteRef.orderByValue().equalTo(itemToDelete).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener()

Comment: http://snippi.com/s/sd20jyv Here it is the full code of the activity. Sorry for my bad style, I'm just learning.

Comment: SO is not a good environment for debugging.  Log the value of `getCurrentUser().getUid()` and confirm that data exists for that UID.

Comment: This is the Log:

D/AcceptFriendReqAct: testfriend1@gmail.com
D/AcceptFriendReqAct: testfriend2@gmail.com
D/AcceptFriendReqAct: Removing item 1: testfriend2@gmail.com
D/AcceptFriendReqAct: CurrentUser: zCh6Q8TvTSiRnteZP6wpom9oAJ3
D/AcceptFriendReqAct: OnDataChange

As you can see it stops to "OnDataChange", but it doesn't print "Snapshot exists".

I think database is ok because I can read items and display them with an Adapter

http://it.tinypic.com/r/9s5kph/9 This is the full database

Comment: You log shows  `CurrentUser: zCh6Q8TvTSiRnteZP6wpom9oAJ3`.  The database has that UID but with an 'r' prefix: `rzCh6Q8TvTSiRnteZP6wpom9oAJ3`.

Comment: Sorry it was just a copy-paste problem. I confirm the currentUser is right... D/AcceptFriendReqAct: Removing item 0: testfriend1@gmail.com
 CurrentUser: rzCh6Q8TvTSiRnteZP6wpom9oAJ3 D/AcceptFriendReqAct: OnDataChange

Comment: The log output (from code line 44) shows `Removing item 1: testfriend2@gmail.com`, which means `itemToDelete` is `testfriend2@gmail.com`.  That is the value of a child of `users`, not `richieste`.  The snapshot probably doesn't exist because there are no children of `richieste` with value `testfriend2@gmail.com`.

Answer (score 1):

To get the `DatabaseReference`, you can call `DataSnapshot.getReF()`, and then you can remove the value by calling `.removeValue()`.

But based on your case, you should iterate the `DataSnapshot` or use `ChildEventListener` to make sure you are removing the child and not the whole data under `richieste/<user_id>`.

To iterate and remove the value:

```
for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
     childSnapshot.getRef().removeValue();
}
```

There's another error in your code, you should store the reference of this line `deleteRef.orderByValue().equalTo(itemToDelete);` to another `DatabaseReference` before attaching the event listener or you can directly attach the listener with this trick `deleteRef.orderByValue().equalTo(itemToDelete).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(...);`

For the bonus question, the `onCancelled` will be called if there's an error reading the database such as network or permission problem.

Hope this helps :)